# extract part of file name using batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have loop, where I'll copy all *.txt files to big.txt in the same directory. In each loop step I want additional copys of different files in different folders with the same first three characters in file name from files in first directory.

Example:

```
\A\001.txt
\A\003.txt
\A\005.txt
\A\big.txt
\B\001_sth.xml
\B\002_sth.xml - don't copy! no 002 in folder A
\B\003_sth.xml
\B\004_sth.xml - don't copy! no 004 in folder A
\B\005_sth.xml
\B\big.xml
```

In step 1: copy \A\001.txt to \A\big.txt AND \B\001_sth.xml to \B\big.xml
etc

I wrote the batch file to only copy files in directory A, but I have no idea how to find files directory B.

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto error 
for %%x in (%1\A\*.txt) do (
    copy %%x %1\A\big.txt
    echo %%x
    echo ---
)   

goto end    
:error
echo give me a directory    
:end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just enumerate files in A and then reference files in B?

```
for %%I in (%1\A\*.txt) do (
    copy %1\B\%%~nI_sth.xml %1\B\big.xml
    echo %%I
    echo ---
)   
goto :EOF
```

(by the way it's not wise to use lower case x for your loop variable because %%~sdfnx  all have special meaning)

Comment: What is `%%x`? Did you mean `%%I`?

Comment: Ah, I see now, it's there because you used the OP's example as a starting point. Sorry about asking silly questions.

Comment: This is what I needed: ~n. Thanks! Also thanks for a good tip about %%x.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the purpose of your code. Each time you copy to big.txt you over-write the previous copy. I think you want to append instead.

I'm not sure if you want to start with an empty big.txt and big.xml. I'm assuming you do.

Also, your question implies the source text files could have more than 3 characters in the name, even though your example has exactly 3. I'm assuming you want to support more than 3.

If I understand you correctly, I think this will work (untested) *Edit - made changes in response to Andriy M comments regarding initial setlocal and avoiding self-copy of big.txt*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"=="" echo Give me a directory&exit /b
set "root=%~1"
if exist "%root%\A\big.txt" del "%root%\A\big.txt"
if exist "%root%\B\big.xml" del "%root%\B\big.xml"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "%root%\A\*.txt"') do (
  type "%root%\A\%%~F" >>"%root%\A\big.txt"
  set "prefix=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  type "!root!\B\!prefix:~0,3!*.xml" >>"!root!\B\big.xml"
  endlocal
)
```

The toggling of the delayed expansion within the loop is only needed if `!` appears in any of the paths. Since this is unlikely, you can probably start out with delayed expansion enabled and drop the toggling.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to watch for `big.txt` as the value of `%%F` to prevent an attempt of self-copying.

Comment: And I've got a question: does `setlocal` (without arguments) imply `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion`?

Comment: SETLOCAL without arg will equate to SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion for most environments, but it would be better to be explicit. I edited the answer. The solution will never attempt to self-copy big.txt because it is deleted prior to starting the loop. The IN() clause is fully evaluated prior to executing the DO block.

Comment: Re "IN() clause is fully evaluated prior to executing…": I would think as much, and in fact I did think so until I saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366864/windows-7-batch-script-for-command-error-bug).

Comment: And thanks for the clarification on `SETLOCAL`, didn't know that (must have missed the relevant bit in the docs).

Comment: @Andriy M, To be more specific - SETLOCAL will preserve the current delayed state, which is normally disabled unless explictly enabled earlier. Interesting, and scary link. I'm curious if the problem is with any FOR or is specific to /R option? I don't have access to Win 7 so I can't test.

Comment: @Andriy M, Ran a test in Vista and I was clearly wrong. I think I was mis-applying something jeb had written about FOR /F which does not apply here. Fixed the code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These would help;

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

http://ss64.com/nt/