# Search for *.html in a folder and run specific code

Tags: types, batch-file

type "S:\Images*.html" | findstr /v Signature | findstr /v sealants | findstr /v construction  >S:\Images\.html

I have developed the above text. I am not the best at batch scripting however know my way around how to use variables (in PHP and C++).

My goal is to update users email signature file. (I am trying to remove three lines of text).
In order to do this I want to search their shared drive for any html files and try and find the three lines I need to remove.

The catch is I am not very good with variables and searching in a batch script. I want to overwrite the file which I am modifying.

Answer (score 1):

how did you come with this code? you should learn how to progress on implementing a solution (being a BAT file or not) step by step, reading the manual, trying yourself, and debugging the problems.

When you do try your code, you'll realize what `TYPE` command does (it does not list a directory). See 'HELP TYPE`.

You need to use `FOR`command. See `HELP FOR`, and then try this in the command line

```
 FOR %a in (*.HTML) do @echo %a
```

and then read `HELP FINDSTR` and try this in the command line

```
 FOR %a in (*.HTML) do @findstr /v "Signature sealants construction" %a
```

And you are almost done. There are minor changes you'll have to do to put it in a .BAT file: to use FOR in a BAT you need to replace the %va to %%a; add some @echo off and other incantations; remove @ in the command lines; ...

Putting all pieces together, tye the following code

```
 @echo off
 FOR %%a in (*.HTML) do (
    FINDSTR /i /v "Signature sealants construction" %%a >%%~na.html.new
 )
 echo del *.html
 echo ren *.html.new *.html
```

test it and modify it to fit your needs, remember, this is only a starting point. When totally correct, remove the `ECHO`.

Comment: This looks really nice and clear, but, judging by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366864/windows-7-batch-script-for-command-error-bug), might behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

```
for "eol=: delims=" %%f in ('findstr /s /m /l "Signature sealants construction" "*.html"') do (
  findstr /l /v "Signature sealants construction" "%%f" >"%%f.tmp"
  del "%%f"
  ren "%%f.tmp" "%%~nxf"
)
```

The above should be run from the folder where you want to begin your search. The outer loop finds all html files containing any of the words. Inside the loop it writes each found file to a .tmp file, stripping out any lines containing at least one of the words. Then it simply deletes the old file and renames the .tmp to the original.

If you want the search to be case sensitive, add the /i option to both FINDSTR commands.

I'm worried that the search is too general. Any of the words could appear in multiple contexts. This could lead to disastrous unintended results. I'm thinking you might need more specific patterns to search for. FINDSTR supports crude regular expressions. If you can figure out a good regular expression for each line to be removed, you could change /l to /r and replace the quoted search string with three /c:"regularExpression" arguments, one per regular expression. Of course this would be done to both FINDSTR commands. It might also help if the name of the .html has some pattern to make it more selective.

Finally, instead of simply over-writing the original .html, it would be safer to keep a copy of the original, just in case something went wrong. I recommend replacing the `del "%%f"` line in my code with

```
  del "%%f.bak" 2>nul
  ren "%%f" "%%~nxf.bak"
```